# Prevent SQL Injection without MySQLi or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

I know that I can use prepared statement to prevent SQL injection. I can do it using MySQLi or PDO. But I have a developed a large CRM using PHP/ MySQL (mysql_query). If I have to change each and every query into PDO or MySQLi, it will take at least a month. The script got more that 500 MySQL query statement.

I really need help in this matter. Can anyone tell me that how to prevent SQL injection not using MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: If you're going back through your code to make changes for sql injections, you're doing the same amount of work as rewriting it to use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way by which I can filter each and every $_GET and $_POST to stop SQL injection?

Comment: No. You need to use prepared statements which is DB functionality.

Comment: Of course one can write safe code using the awful `mysql_` functions. It just requires *way more* attention than most newcomers typically exhibit. And a simple wrapper emulating parameter binding would be all that's necessary. But hardly anyone is doing that either. So it's more a question of which is easier and simpler to ensure. You still had to rewrite *all the things*.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone tell me that how to prevent SQL injection not using MySQLi or PDO [in an existing application which has over 500 raw MySQL statements]?

### Short Answer

No.

Architecturally, your application *needs* a top-to-bottom rewrite (with regards to its database access structures) to become safe on the web.  Going hog-wild with data sanitizers and statement heuristics would be *far more dangerous and time-consuming* than simply implementing a reliable SQL abstraction layer as part of your revision strategy.

My recommendation is that you at least implement **Doctrine**.  Probably the [Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) would be a good start, especially for a port from a legacy database strategy like the one you described; or go a step up with the [Doctrine Object Relational Mapper (ORM)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/).  Better yet, build your future applications (or application re-builds) using a framework that already includes these database libraries, like [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) or [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please tell me that how much safe codeigniter is.